# Android Material Animation with Splash Screen like Palabre Application

Tags: android, android-animation, material-design

Here is the SplashScreen of `Palabre` view:

[image]

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.levelup.palabre

As we can see, at the start of application, there is a SplashScreen with image Animation.

And here is what i'm trying to achieve this beauty :) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/grand_canyon"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Result:**

[image]

And this SplashActivity have a full screen view.So,

How we can move this image exactly like `Palabre` on the left or right?
 and what is the size of Image at this Screen?

**Edit:**

also i found this for full screen imageview:
in your layout:

```
android:scaleType = "centerCrop"
```

and what we need to add animation to this imageview?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it finally.It's beautifull :)
just add the dependency:

```
compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.6'
```

and,

**XML Layout:**

```
<com.flaviofaria.kenburnsview.KenBurnsView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:scaleType = "centerCrop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/splash" />
```

**Github:** https://github.com/flavioarfaria/KenBurnsView

thanks to Flávio Faria for this good library.

But, it has a problem and that is, when the image is going to another side, it's like a bug or something like stucking and i couldn't find the best solution yet.

Answer (score 3):

I think that with a mix of Scale and TranslateAnimation you can do the trick.

Another option is using an AnimationSet (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html)

EDIT: Here are some examples of ObjectAnimator with several animations where myView is the view that you want to animate. Check this link for an explanation of the animation properties (rotationX, rotationY, etc) http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#views

```
 AnimatorSet animSet = new AnimatorSet();
    animSet.playTogether(
         ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "rotationX", 0, 360),
         ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "rotationY", 0, 180),
         ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "rotation", 0, -90),
         ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "translationX", 0, 90),
         ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "translationY", 0, 90),
         ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "scaleX", 1, 1.5f),
         ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "scaleY", 1, 0.5f),
         ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "alpha", 1, 0.25f, 1)
    );
 animSet.setDuration(5000).start();
```

Check also that I asigned a duration of the animation in milliseconds.

If you are targeting API's below 11, check http://nineoldandroids.com/ to use AnimatorSet on older androids.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think you should do

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"  
     android:background="@drawable/ic_splash" >
</RelativeLayout>
```